# What is the song playing on the radio in X-Men: Days of future past?

Tags: analysis, soundtrack, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

When Wolverine awakes in his 1973 self in [X-Men: Days of Future Past](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1877832/) he hears a song on the radio. This same song is heard when he awakes in his future self again at the end of the movie, which is likely to evoke feelings of Déjà vu in him (and the audience) and to let him doubt reality for a moment.

What song is this and is there any further significance to this particular song?

Comment: As a side note, it was the same song that played when he woke up in '73 and was used in the future to evoke feelings of Déjà vu in *Logan* and the audience.

Comment: Yup. That's the one.

Comment: In light of the [current meta discussion](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1296/49) about such questions, I tried to give it a bit more substance apart from a mere *"what's this song?"*. I hope the new version of the question is still in your interest, but feel free to revert it if it isn't.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Much appreciated.

Comment: When logan wakes up in the present at the end of the movie the title on the radio globe thing says golden oldie. Not sure what that means but I did just read about Sony wanting to release an aunt may solo movie from the amazing spider man series and golden oldie was one of the super hero characaters aunt may becomes. Coincidence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This song was *Roberta Flack*'s version of ["The First Time Ever I Saw Your Face"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_First_Time_Ever_I_Saw_Your_Face).

I can't say much to the significance of its usage, though. But for one, it was released around '70 and was a major hit in 1972. So it was hot at the time when *Logan* awakes in the past (1973). It was thus first and foremost part of the many 70's nostalgia elements that the movie employed and, as *Andrew* points out in his comment, a way to easily show and emphasize that *Logan* has indeed traveled back in time. It's use then in the future (2023) when he awakes again was probably just to evoke that *Déjà vu* feeling in *Logan* and us, without much particular significance to the actual song, I'd say.

Comment: I think this is just a way of signifying he's arrived back in time, similar to "Mr Sandman" playing in Back to the Future when Marty McFly goes back in time.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Good point, included.

Comment: That's the one! The first hit on Google search is a youtube video and some of the people have already referenced DOFP there.

Comment: Anyone know the version that they used in the movie?

Comment: @BobbyAlexander What do you mean *"the version"*. Are there more? Wikipedia and my ears clearly say that it's *Roberta Flack*'s version, but has she done more than one?

Comment: Although it is the same song, it sounds a bit different in the movie

Comment: @BobbyAlexander Can you point me to that YouTube video? As I think the version presented on Wikipedia sounds exactly like the movie.

Comment: Well what do you know... its there on iTunes. I should have checked before I posted the question!

Comment: @BobbyAlexander Thanks for accepting, but could you still give that YouTube link to clear any confusion?

Comment: Here you go: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=kp&gl=SG&hl=en-GB&v=Go9aks4aujM